# Room schema validation fails for view in pre-packaged database on adding where clause

Tags: android, android-room

I am getting the following error when installing my app stating that the view does not match, even though expected and found are identical:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: history_view(..data.schema.entity.view.HistoryItemView).
Expected:
ViewInfo{name='history_view', sql='CREATE VIEW `history_view` AS SELECT
               d.entity_id AS organisationId,
               m._id AS measurementId,
               m.corrected_datetime AS timestamp,
               ec.ECValue AS ecValue,
               ec.ECStatus AS ecStatus,
               mc.MCValue AS mcValue,
               mc.MCStatus AS mcStatus,
               ph.pHValue AS phValue,
               ph.pHStatus AS phStatus,
               pm.temperature AS temperatureInCelsius,
               m_nt.text_content as noteText,
               tv.value AS mediaName,
               tt.type AS mediaNameType,
               m_nt._id AS noteId
           FROM device AS d
               LEFT JOIN measurement AS m on d._id = m.device_id
               LEFT JOIN pulse_measurement AS pm ON pm.measurement_id = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_ec.measurement_id as ECMeasurementId,
                   rv_ec.value AS ECValue,
                   st_ec.type AS ECStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_ec
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ec ON rv_ec.type_id = rvt_ec._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ec ON rv_ec.status_id = st_ec._id
                   WHERE rvt_ec.type = 'EC' COLLATE NOCASE) AS ec ON ec.ECMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_mc.measurement_id as MCMeasurementId,
                   rv_mc.value AS MCValue,
                   st_mc.type AS MCStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_mc
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_mc ON rv_mc.type_id = rvt_mc._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_mc ON rv_mc.status_id = st_mc._id
                   WHERE rvt_mc.type = 'MC' COLLATE NOCASE) as mc ON mc.MCMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_ph.measurement_id as pHMeasurementId,
                   rv_ph.value AS pHValue,
                   st_ph.type AS pHStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_ph
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ph ON rv_ph.type_id = rvt_ph._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ph ON rv_ph.status_id = st_ph._id
                   WHERE rvt_ph.type = 'pH' COLLATE NOCASE) as ph ON ph.pHMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN measurement_note AS mn ON mn.measurement_id = m._id
               LEFT JOIN note AS m_nt ON m_nt._id = mn.note_id
               LEFT JOIN media AS med ON pm.model_global_id LIKE med.global_id
               LEFT JOIN text_value AS tv ON med.name_id = tv._id
               LEFT JOIN text_type AS tt on tv.text_type_id = tt._id
            WHERE m.deleted = 0
       UNION
           SELECT
               u.entity_id AS organisationId,
               NULL AS measurementId,
               nt.time_stamp AS timestamp,
               NULL AS ecValue,
               NULL AS ecStatus,
               NULL AS mcValue,
               NULL AS mcStatus,
               NULL AS phValue,
               NULL AS phStatus,
               NULL AS temperatureInCelsius,
               nt.text_content as noteText,
               NULL AS mediaName,
               NULL AS mediaNameType,
               nt._id as noteId
           FROM note AS nt
               LEFT JOIN user AS u ON nt.user_id = u._id
           WHERE nt._id NOT IN ( SELECT note_id from measurement_note ) AND nt.deleted = 0
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC'}
Found:
ViewInfo{name='history_view', sql='CREATE VIEW history_view AS SELECT
            d.entity_id AS organisationId,
            m._id AS measurementId,
            m.corrected_datetime AS timestamp,
            ec.ECValue AS ecValue,
            ec.ECStatus AS ecStatus,
            mc.MCValue AS mcValue,
            mc.MCStatus AS mcStatus,
            ph.pHValue AS phValue,
            ph.pHStatus AS phStatus,
            pm.temperature AS temperatureInCelsius,
            m_nt.text_content as noteText,
            tv.value AS mediaName,
            tt.type AS mediaNameType,
            m_nt._id AS noteId
            FROM device AS d
            LEFT JOIN measurement AS m on d._id = m.device_id
            LEFT JOIN pulse_measurement AS pm ON pm.measurement_id = m._id
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
            rv_ec.measurement_id as ECMeasurementId,
            rv_ec.value AS ECValue,
            st_ec.type AS ECStatus
            FROM ranged_value AS rv_ec
            LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ec ON rv_ec.type_id = rvt_ec._id
            LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ec ON rv_ec.status_id = st_ec._id
            WHERE rvt_ec.type = 'EC' COLLATE NOCASE) AS ec ON ec.ECMeasurementId = m._id
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
            rv_mc.measurement_id as MCMeasurementId,
            rv_mc.value AS MCValue,
            st_mc.type AS MCStatus
            FROM ranged_value AS rv_mc
            LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_mc ON rv_mc.type_id = rvt_mc._id
            LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_mc ON rv_mc.status_id = st_mc._id
            WHERE rvt_mc.type = 'MC' COLLATE NOCASE) as mc ON mc.MCMeasurementId = m._id
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
            rv_ph.measurement_id as pHMeasurementId,
            rv_ph.value AS pHValue,
            st_ph.type AS pHStatus
            FROM ranged_value AS rv_ph
            LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ph ON rv_ph.type_id = rvt_ph._id
            LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ph ON rv_ph.status_id = st_ph._id
            WHERE rvt_ph.type = 'pH' COLLATE NOCASE) as ph ON ph.pHMeasurementId = m._id
            LEFT JOIN measurement_note AS mn ON mn.measurement_id = m._id
            LEFT JOIN note AS m_nt ON m_nt._id = mn.note_id
            LEFT JOIN media AS med ON pm.model_global_id LIKE med.global_id
            LEFT JOIN text_value AS tv ON med.name_id = tv._id
            LEFT JOIN text_type AS tt on tv.text_type_id = tt._id
            WHERE m.deleted = 0
            UNION
            SELECT
            u.entity_id AS organisationId,
            NULL AS measurementId,
            nt.time_stamp AS timestamp,
            NULL AS ecValue,
            NULL AS ecStatus,
            NULL AS mcValue,
            NULL AS mcStatus,
            NULL AS phValue,
            NULL AS phStatus,
            NULL AS temperatureInCelsius,
            nt.text_content as noteText,
            NULL AS mediaName,
            NULL AS mediaNameType,
            nt._id as noteId
            FROM note AS nt
            LEFT JOIN user AS u ON nt.user_id = u._id
            WHERE nt._id NOT IN ( SELECT note_id from measurement_note ) AND nt.deleted = 0
            ORDER BY timestamp DESC'}
```

This is the view class:

```
@DatabaseView(value = """
     SELECT
               d.entity_id AS organisationId,
               m._id AS measurementId,
               m.corrected_datetime AS timestamp,
               ec.ECValue AS ecValue,
               ec.ECStatus AS ecStatus,
               mc.MCValue AS mcValue,
               mc.MCStatus AS mcStatus,
               ph.pHValue AS phValue,
               ph.pHStatus AS phStatus,
               pm.temperature AS temperatureInCelsius,
               m_nt.text_content as noteText,
               tv.value AS mediaName,
               tt.type AS mediaNameType,
               m_nt._id AS noteId
           FROM device AS d
               LEFT JOIN measurement AS m on d._id = m.device_id
               LEFT JOIN pulse_measurement AS pm ON pm.measurement_id = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_ec.measurement_id as ECMeasurementId,
                   rv_ec.value AS ECValue,
                   st_ec.type AS ECStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_ec
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ec ON rv_ec.type_id = rvt_ec._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ec ON rv_ec.status_id = st_ec._id
                   WHERE rvt_ec.type = 'EC' COLLATE NOCASE) AS ec ON ec.ECMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_mc.measurement_id as MCMeasurementId,
                   rv_mc.value AS MCValue,
                   st_mc.type AS MCStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_mc
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_mc ON rv_mc.type_id = rvt_mc._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_mc ON rv_mc.status_id = st_mc._id
                   WHERE rvt_mc.type = 'MC' COLLATE NOCASE) as mc ON mc.MCMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                   rv_ph.measurement_id as pHMeasurementId,
                   rv_ph.value AS pHValue,
                   st_ph.type AS pHStatus
                   FROM ranged_value AS rv_ph
                   LEFT JOIN ranged_value_type AS rvt_ph ON rv_ph.type_id = rvt_ph._id
                   LEFT JOIN status_type AS st_ph ON rv_ph.status_id = st_ph._id
                   WHERE rvt_ph.type = 'pH' COLLATE NOCASE) as ph ON ph.pHMeasurementId = m._id
               LEFT JOIN measurement_note AS mn ON mn.measurement_id = m._id
               LEFT JOIN note AS m_nt ON m_nt._id = mn.note_id
               LEFT JOIN media AS med ON pm.model_global_id LIKE med.global_id
               LEFT JOIN text_value AS tv ON med.name_id = tv._id
               LEFT JOIN text_type AS tt on tv.text_type_id = tt._id
            WHERE m.deleted = 0
       UNION
           SELECT
               u.entity_id AS organisationId,
               NULL AS measurementId,
               nt.time_stamp AS timestamp,
               NULL AS ecValue,
               NULL AS ecStatus,
               NULL AS mcValue,
               NULL AS mcStatus,
               NULL AS phValue,
               NULL AS phStatus,
               NULL AS temperatureInCelsius,
               nt.text_content as noteText,
               NULL AS mediaName,
               NULL AS mediaNameType,
               nt._id as noteId
           FROM note AS nt
               LEFT JOIN user AS u ON nt.user_id = u._id
           WHERE nt._id NOT IN ( SELECT note_id from measurement_note ) AND nt.deleted = 0
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        """,
viewName = "history_view")
data class HistoryItemView(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "organisationId", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
        val organisationId: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "measurementId", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
        val measurementId: Long?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
        val timestamp: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ecValue", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
        val ecValue: Float?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ecStatus", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val ecStatus: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "mcValue", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
        val mcValue: Float?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "mcStatus", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val mcStatus: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "phValue", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
        val phValue: Float?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "phStatus", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val phStatus: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "temperatureInCelsius", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.REAL)
        val temperatureInCelsius: Double?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "noteText", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val noteText: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "mediaName", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val mediaName: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "mediaNameType", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
        val mediaNameType: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "noteId", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.INTEGER)
        val noteId: Long?
)
```

The problem appeared after adding the following lines:
`WHERE m.deleted = 0` and  `AND nt.deleted = 0` and `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`

Running the select query directly on the database returns the values as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the inclusion of whitespaces. In copying the select query from my database script to my view class I somehow added a space to the end of each line. When comparing the two pieces of sql they seemed identical until I turned whitespace comparison on.

Comment: glad you found the problem!!